# Unable to install Windows 7 because startup CD does not support USB devices

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, usb

I had a virus on Windows 7 and wanted to re-install it before Microsoft's end of life ended so I could get updates for it. I reformatted the drive and when I ran the bootable CD, it did not support USB devices. So my mouse and keyboard would not work. I have an old keyboard, but my motherboard does not have the correct receptacle. I used to have an adapter, but I can't find it. I'll have to order a couple. I will check to make sure 'USB Legacy Support' is enabled it the BIOS, but I think it is. Because of this I cannot get the information for my previous question 'Unable to Login after Switching to Local Account in Windows 10' because I cant access Windows 10 either. It is dual-boot.

I tried to install Windows 10 where Windows 7 was, but it won't boot either. The boot sector is on the same drive where Window 7 was. I tried to run Partition Magic, but I only early versions of it burnt onto DVDs. My video card would not run it. I'm trying to burn the latest edition now and see if I can either fix the boot sector or totally make the disk one partition and reformat it. If anybody has any suggestions, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: **Windows 7 will be out of support in a few dfays**. Don't waste time with it. Install Windows 10 with a USB stick made with the official media creation tool or, even better, move to some beginner friendly Linux like Ubuntu.

Comment: This doesnt make sense.  Windows 7 absolutely supports USB devices from the installer.  Is this an OEM installer disc?  And USB legacy support in the BIOS is for OSs that dont support USB, like DOS.  It will have no effect on Windows 7.

Comment: @Keltari; Windows 7 does not support USB3 out of the box, and UEFI firmwares do not usually emulate legacy keyboard/mouse support the way legacy BIOSes typically do.  If the OP does not have a USB2 port (and if his firmware didn't emulate legacy USB support), then he would need to load USB3 drivers in PE setup.  Fortunately, he found a workaround, but this was a common problem with Win7 when USB3 first hit the market.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Windows 7 installed. I ordered the PS2 adapters and a PS2 mouse. I am using a Asus Rog Maximus IX Hero motherboard and I checked that the USB Legacy was enabled and it was. In Advanced -> USB Config, I then noticed a setting named 'USB Keyboard and Mouse Simulator' which was disabled. When I highlighted it, it mentioned something about PS2, so I enabled it. I then ran the Windows 7 install DVD. When it opened, I had both my mouse and keyboard. I then installed Win 7 with no problem.